# How to obtain search query using join command in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table 
Table 1:
Ensemble_ID
Target 
Gene_length
miRNA
miRNA_length
mfe
pvalue
position
prediction
no_of_seeds

And in table2
Ensemble_ID
local_ID

I want to display the result in the following order, 
Ensemble_ID, local_ID, Ensemble_ID, Target ,Gene_length, miRNA, miRNA_length, mfe, pvalue, position, prediction, no_of_seeds

But i could not join it .. Can some one help ??

Comment: You need two columns with **Ensemble_ID ** , local_ID, **Ensemble_ID** , Target ,Gene_length, miRNA, miRNA_length, mfe, pvalue, position, prediction, no_of_seeds?

Show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are asking:

```
    SELECT t1.Ensemble_ID AS Ensemble_ID1, t2.local_ID, t2.Ensemble_ID AS Ensemble_ID2, 
       t1.Target, t1.Gene_length, t1.miRNA, 
       t1.miRNA_length, t1.mfe, t1.pvalue, t1.position, t1.prediction, t1.no_of_seeds
    FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

But it think you want something like this:

```
SELECT t2.local_ID, t2.Ensemble_ID, t1.Target, t1.Gene_length, t1.miRNA, 
  t1.miRNA_length, t1.mfe, t1.pvalue, t1.position, t1.prediction, t1.no_of_seeds
FROM table1 t1
      INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.Ensemble_ID = t1.Ensemble_ID)
```

If you want to join table1 and table2 on Ensemble_ID there is no need to output it twice